# Whats wrong in this if statement?

Tags: java

The code:

```
// message is a string , a1 is an integer array .. both well defined
if(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(message.charAt(i))) == (a1[i - 1] + a1[i])) {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code by putting four spaces before each line, or by selecting it and pressing the "101010" button in the editor.

Comment: C:\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\Topcoder>javac *.java
BinaryCode.java:29: illegal start of expression
                if(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(message.charAt(i)))) == (
a2[i - 1] + a2[i]))
                                                                            ^
BinaryCode.java:29: ';' expected
                if(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(message.charAt(i)))) == (
a2[i - 1] + a2[i]))

Comment: Can you at least post the definitions of message and a1?

Comment: At what point is the `^` pointing at? javac error messages and SO comments don't really get along.

Comment: @D.J. The code in your question and the code in your comment are **different**.  How do you expect people to spot your syntax errors if you don't provide the real code???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 too many `)` at the end of `charAt` which closes your if condition.

Comment: The real problem is that the if condition is too complicated. By extracting the parts into meaningful variables, it'd be easier to read and perhaps not become a problem. For example, what does "a1[i - 1] + a1[i]" mean? Let's say it's the expected sum, then assign it to the variable int expectedSum. So in the end, this if condition might look like "if (extractedNumber == expectedSum)" which is kinder to the eyes and easier to read.

Comment: As markali has pointed out the code is not very readable and this sort of problem is to be expected with unreadable code. 
Don't be tempted to write such code in the assumption that assigning some of these expressions to variables is going to slow your program. It will not happen.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the syntax error:

1. It's too complicated. Use local variables to compute intermediate results.
2. Use `Character.getNumericValue(ch)` instead of `Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(ch))`.

Answer (score 1):

What is `i`? If it is `0`, `a1[i - 1]` would throw exception.

Comment: And if it were <0 or >= a1.length an exception would also be thrown by the supplied code.

Comment: @SM - That's true, but loops are generally from `0` to `a.length - 1`.